# SQL Server strange connection issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

When I connect to my live SQL server database. Despite of giving the database it displays a long list of databases. I have to look up my database among these all databases.

Is there any way so that I can view only my database when connect to the server?

Comment: What are you connecting with, management studio or some other application?

Comment: When you connect with management studio you see all databases. This may look strange, but it is the way that management studio works. I do not know if there is a way to limit the list. It would be nice to find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the [`VIEW ANY DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077.aspx) permission revoked on the login you are using.

I just tested setting up a new login called `bar` and running `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO bar;` but that failed with the message

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner,
>   information_schema, sys, or yourself.

So you will need to get the sysadmin to do this.